# Youtube live streaming broadcast in android

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Im trying to develop an android application for youtube live streaming broadcast. Is it possible to stream live video from Android app to Youtube live channel on Youtube?. but i didn't get any link for broadcast live streaming. is there any way to implement?

im looking for simple solution to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you sloved this ?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java

If you create the live event in your youtube dashboard(you can also create it using https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme ), you can get the stream key for the broadcast. Using that stream key, you can directly broadcast video from the android app. Please have a look at the above github project. Answering the older question but it may be useful for someone.